# The virtual machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I can not start Hyper V virtual machines. I am getting following message:

```
[Window Title]
Virtual Machine Connection

[Main Instruction]
The application encountered an error while attempting to change the state of 'Ubuntu'.

[Content]
'Ubuntu' could not initialize.

The virtual machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running. 

[Expanded Information]
'Ubuntu' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID 482FFAEF-4BDD-4C1D-86D8-A505A5196EFC)

The virtual machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running.  The following actions may help you resolve the problem:

1) Verify that the processor of the physical computer has a supported version of hardware-assisted virtualization.

2) Verify that hardware-assisted virtualization and hardware-assisted data execution protection are enabled in the BIOS of the physical computer.  (If you edit the BIOS to enable either setting, you must turn off the power to the physical computer and then turn it back on.  Resetting the physical computer is not sufficient.)

3) If you have made changes to the Boot Configuration Data store, review these changes to ensure that the hypervisor is configured to launch automatically.



[^] Hide details  [Close]
```

I've checked that Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. My CPU - `AMD Athlon/Karbini 5350` and motherboard - `ASRock am1b-itx`. OS - `Windows Server 2008 R2`.

I've also tried VMWare and it works (I've uninstalled it already and do not have any other virtual machines on the machine).

What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

So finally I've found the solution. After re-installing OS, playing with BIOS, trying all possible solution on the internet I finally found it:
http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/690662-AMD-FX-series-and-Hyper-V.
The issue was with my CPU + OS. I just needed to install [this patch](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix369475/7600/free/434304_intl_x64_zip.exe) ...